# How to manage radio button state with React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, radio-button

I am implementing a simple signup page with React Typescript.
I'm trying to set the gender with the radio button, save it in the state, and send it to the server, but the toggle doesn't work.
What should I do?

```
//RegisterPage.tsx
const [radioState, setradioState] = useState(null);
const [toggle, settoggle] = useState<boolean>(false);

const onRadioChange = (e: any) => {
    setradioState(e);
    console.log(radioState);
  };

const genderOps: ops[] = [
    { view: "man", value: "man" },
    { view: "woman", value: "woman" },
  ];
```

```
<div>
          {genderOps.map(({ title, gender }: any) => {
            return (
              <>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value={gender}
                  name={gender}
                  checked={gender === radioState}
                  onChange={(e) => onRadioChange(gender)}
                />
                {title}
              </>
            );
          })}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do some changes on your code, here what you should do:

```
import React, { EventHandler, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [radioState, setradioState] = useState("");
  const [toggle, settoggle] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const onRadioChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setradioState(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const genderOps = [
    { view: "man", value: "man" },
    { view: "woman", value: "woman" }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {genderOps.map(({ view: title, value: gender }: any) => {
          return (
            <>
              <input
                type="radio"
                value={gender}
                name={gender}
                checked={gender === radioState}
                onChange={(e) => onRadioChange(e)}
              />
              {title}
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you!
The action works fine. But eslint is sending an error by using the any type, is there a solution?```Unexpected any. Specify a different type```

Comment: Updated the answer, just replace `any` with `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`